# Brutal and Crit Dice (from High-Crit or Magic Weapons)

Tags: dnd-4e, critical-hit

How does a brutal weapon interact with crit dice that are granted through a magic weapon or a high-crit weapon?

Examples:

1. **+2 Magic Mordenkrad, 2d6, Brutal 1. 2d6 on critical hit.** Obviously the dice rolled for [W] damage are brutal 1. Are the 2d6 crit dice brutal 1 as well or are they treated as normal dice?
2. **Mundane Executioner's axe. d12, Brutal 2, high-crit.** The dice rolled for normal [W] damage are Brutal 2. Are the [W] dice granted by high-crit brutal 2 as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. **No** the extra 2d6 are not brutal.  Dice granted via a magic weapon are not [W] damage, but extra dice.
2. **Yes**, the extra dice granted by high-crit are brutal as they are specifically [W] damage.

From the [Adventurer's Vault FAQ](http://wizards.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1423/%7E/faq-for-the-adventure%27s-vault!)

> **I am wielding a magic weapon with brutal 2. If I roll a critical hit, do I get to re-roll 1s and 2s when I roll for the bonus damage?**
>
> No, the brutal weapon trait only applies to rolls for normal weapon damage, signified by [W]. The bonus damage for critical hits does not qualify for this. However, because high crit adds a [W] roll (or 2[W] or 3[W] depending on your level), you would get to re-roll any 1s or 2s.